# MongoDB aggregation add months or years to a Date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We can use `$add` to [add Dates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) in the aggregation pipe. Is there a way to add a specific number of time units (ie days months or years) except milliseconds?

The current way to add 3 years is `date: { $add: [ "$date", 3*365*24*60*60000 ] }`

My expected syntax format is `date: { $add: [ "$date", { $years:3 } ] }` which is not working

Comment: How do you cover leap years?

Comment: Is this request urgent? If not, wait for Mongo 5.0 it will be released soon. There it provides [$dateAdd()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you will get this function Mongo 5.0

In the meantime you can use this workaround:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $addFields: {
         new_date: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: { $add: [{ $year: "$date" }, 3] },
               month: { $month: "$date" },
               day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },
               hour: { $hour: "$date" },
               minute: { $minute: "$date" },
               second: { $second: "$date" },
               millisecond: { $millisecond: "$date" }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: This is a very creative workaround. Considering your comments on the question, my approach cannot address leap years or even it cannot add months. But this solution should handle them properly.  Thank you